Como abrir un archivo directamente con un form
Tengo un programa de un bloc de notas en c# en Windows Forms y me gustaría saber como hacer una cosa:
El notepad de Windows se puede definir como predeterminado para abrir archivos de texto (*.txt). Querría saber como hacer eso mismo con mi app y se abra el texto en el textBox que he puesto en el main form (Por ahora lo pongo como predeterminado, pero no se me abre el texto).
Gracias desde ahora por contestar.

Eso se defini en el registro de windows.. al instalar tu programa...

Si ya tienes registrado el programa, el sistema te pasa como parámetro de llamada el nombre del archivo que el usuario quiere abrir (por ejemplo, al que ha hecho doble clic en el shell).
